# How can I update a view's progress bar using the AppSync S3ObjectManager?

Tags: ios, swift, aws-appsync

I'm using `AWSAppSyncClient` to upload files but I'm struggling to connect the upload progress hook with the view.

`AWSAppSyncClient` is a property of the the application delegate initialized with an `S3ObjectManager`. The object manager method `upload` has access to the upload progress via the `AWSTransferUtilityUplaodExpression`:

```
  expression.progressBlock = {(task, progress) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
      // Can we update the controller's progress bar here?
      print("Progress: \(Float(progress.fractionCompleted))")
    })
  }
```

My controller invokes the upload by calling `perform`:

```
var appSyncClient: AWSAppSyncClient? // retrieved from the app delegate singleton

appSyncClient?.perform(mutation: CreatePostMutation(input: input)) { (result, error) in ...
```

**What I am struggling with:** how do I provide the `S3ObjectManager` a reference to the controller? I thought of instantiating the `AWSAppSyncClient` in each controller, and maybe using some sort of delegate pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably overkill to instantiate a new client on each view controller. Setup & teardown take a bit of time & system resources to perform, and you'd probably prefer to keep those activities separate from the view controller in any case, just for separation of responsibilities.

There isn't really a good way of registering a per-object listener, since mutations are queued for eventual, asynchronous delivery. Your delegate idea seems like the best approach at this point.

**NOTE: Code below is untested, and not thread-safe.**

For example, you could declare a singleton delegate that manages watchers for individual views that need to report progress:

```
class AppSyncS3ObjectManagerProgressWatcher {
    typealias ProgressSubscription = UUID
    static let shared = AppSyncS3ObjectManagerProgressWatcher()
    private var watchers = [UUID: AppSyncS3ObjectManagerProgressDelegate?]()

    func add(_ watcher: AppSyncS3ObjectManagerProgressDelegate) -> ProgressSubscription {
        let subscription = UUID()
        weak var weakWatcher = watcher
        watchers[subscription] = weakWatcher
        return subscription
    }

    func remove(_ subscription: ProgressSubscription?) {
        guard let subscription = subscription else {
            return
        }
        watchers[subscription] = nil
    }
}

extension AppSyncS3ObjectManagerProgressWatcher: AppSyncS3ObjectManagerProgressDelegate {
    func progressReportingExpression(forDownloadingObject object: AWSS3ObjectProtocol) -> AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadExpression {
        let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadExpression()
        expression.progressBlock = { _, progress in
            self.didReportProgress(forDownloadingObject: object, progress: progress)
        }
        return expression
    }

    func progressReportingExpression(forUploadingObject object: AWSS3ObjectProtocol & AWSS3InputObjectProtocol) -> AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression {
        let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
        expression.progressBlock = { _, progress in
            self.didReportProgress(forUploadingObject: object, progress: progress)
        }
        return expression
    }

    func didReportProgress(forDownloadingObject object: AWSS3ObjectProtocol, progress: Progress) {
        for watcher in watchers.values {
            watcher?.didReportProgress(forDownloadingObject: object, progress: progress)
        }
    }

    func didReportProgress(forUploadingObject object: AWSS3ObjectProtocol & AWSS3InputObjectProtocol, progress: Progress) {
        for watcher in watchers.values {
            watcher?.didReportProgress(forUploadingObject: object, progress: progress)
        }
    }
}
```

Wherever you conform S3TransferUtility to S3ObjectManager, you would do something like:

```
extension AWSS3TransferUtility: AWSS3ObjectManager {

    public func download(s3Object: AWSS3ObjectProtocol, toURL: URL, completion: @escaping ((Bool, Error?) -> Void)) {

        let completionBlock: AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadCompletionHandlerBlock = { task, url, data, error -> Void in
            if let _ = error {
                completion(false, error)
            } else {
                completion(true, nil)
            }
        }

        let progressReportingExpression = AppSyncS3ObjectManagerProgressWatcher
            .shared
            .progressReportingExpression(forDownloadingObject: s3Object)

        let _ = self.download(
            to: toURL,
            bucket: s3Object.getBucketName(),
            key: s3Object.getKeyName(),
            expression: progressReportingExpression,
            completionHandler: completionBlock)
    }

    public func upload(s3Object: AWSS3ObjectProtocol & AWSS3InputObjectProtocol, completion: @escaping ((_ success: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> Void)) {
        let completionBlock : AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock = { task, error -> Void in
            if let _ = error {
                completion(false, error)
            } else {
                completion(true, nil)
            }
        }

        let progressReportingExpression = AppSyncS3ObjectManagerProgressWatcher
            .shared
            .progressReportingExpression(forUploadingObject: s3Object)

        let _ = self.uploadFile(
            s3Object.getLocalSourceFileURL()!,
            bucket: s3Object.getBucketName(),
            key: s3Object.getKeyName(),
            contentType: s3Object.getMimeType(),
            expression: progressReportingExpression,
            completionHandler: completionBlock
            ).continueWith { (task) -> Any? in
            if let err = task.error {
                completion(false, err)
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

And then in the progress reporting view:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    progressSubscription = AppSyncS3ObjectManagerProgressWatcher.shared.add(self)
}

func didReportProgress(forUploadingObject object: AWSS3InputObjectProtocol & AWSS3ObjectProtocol, progress: Progress) {
    // TODO: Filter by object local URI/key/etc to ensure we're updating the correct progress
    print("Progress received for \(object.getKeyName()): \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
    self.progress = progress
}
```

As I noted, this code is untested, but it should outline a general approach for you to start from. I'd welcome your feedback and would like to hear what approach you eventually settle on.

Finally, please feel free to open a feature request on our issues page: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-ios/issues

Comment: wow, i'm grateful you took the time to type this up @Palpatim, many thanks! I had a vague idea but this gives me some great stuff to work with, I'll post a gist of what I get working for sure.

Comment: Sure thing, hope it proves useful.